# Casts of generic classes in mutableMap

Tags: kotlin, generics

In my application I want to do something like this:

```
interface Binder<in VB: ViewBinding, in T: Any> {
    fun bind(binding: VB, item: T)
}

class TypeInfoMap {
    val map = mutableMapOf<Class<out Any>, Binder<ViewBinding, Any>>()

    inline fun <reified VB: ViewBinding, reified T: Any> put(binder: Binder<VB, T>) {
        map[T::class.java] = binder as Binder<ViewBinding, Any> // warning unchecked cast
    }

    inline fun <reified VB: ViewBinding, reified T: Any> get(cls: Class<T>): Binder<VB, T> {
        return map[cls] as? Binder<VB, T> ?: throw IllegalStateException() // no warning
    }
}
```

I get the warning `unchecked cast` in the put function. Why is that? I declared upper bounds for the generic types, shouldn't the cast be fine here? Also the cast in the get function does not produce any warning, even when I don't inline the function. I would have thought I would get a warning here and I'm actually surprised that I don't get one.

Is there a way in Kotlin to write all of this without warnings? I thought that's what `reified` is for.

Comment: The parameters of `Binder` are not `refied`. Aside from this, a `Binder<VB, T>` is not a `Binder<ViewBinding, Any>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is incorrect to cast from `Binder<VB, T>` to `Binder<ViewBinding, Any>`. If `binder` is defined as a `Binder<VB, T>`, you can call `binder.bind()` with a `VB` instance, but not with `ViewBinding` instances that are not `VB`s. So a `Binder<VB, T>` is not a `Binder<ViewBinding, Any>`.

Second, the `unchecked cast` warning is not about whether the cast is valid or not. It's about the fact that you won't get a `ClassCastException` at runtime if the type is not correct. This is why it's dangerous.

You probably don't get an unchecked cast warning in the `get()` method because the cast is always valid anyway: a `Binder<ViewBinding, Any>` is always a `Binder<VB, T>` given the variance of `Binder` and the declared parent types of `VB` and `T`.

> Is there a way in Kotlin to write all of this without warnings? I thought that's what reified is for.

`reified` allows to access the generic types at runtime, but only those of the reified function. So for instance they allow you to get the `KClass` of some instance without explicitly passing it. However, the internal map you're using will still give no information at runtime about what you put in it in the past.

The best you can do is ignore the unchecked cast warning because you won't be able to know the generic types contained in the map at runtime. However, you have a more type-safe approach if you make the `map` private because you can control what you put in it:

```kotlin
class TypeInfoMap {
    private val map = mutableMapOf<Key<*, *>, Binder<*, *>>()

    class Key<VB : ViewBinding, T : Any>(
        val bindingClass: KClass<VB>,
        val valueClass: KClass<T>,
    )

    fun <VB : ViewBinding, T : Any> put(key: Key<VB, T>, binder: Binder<VB, T>) {
        map[key] = binder
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") // types are guaranteed by put()
    fun <VB : ViewBinding, T : Any> get(key: Key<VB, T>): Binder<VB, T> {
        val binder = map[key] ?: error("No binding of type ${key.bindingClass} found for class ${key.valueClass}")
        return binder as Binder<VB, T>
    }

    inline fun <reified VB: ViewBinding, reified T: Any> put(binder: Binder<VB, T>) {
        put(Key(VB::class, T::class), binder)
    }

    inline fun <reified VB: ViewBinding, reified T: Any> get(): Binder<VB, T> = get(Key(VB::class, T::class))
}
```

You can then use it safely with nice reified types:

```kotlin
val infoMap = TypeInfoMap()

val someBinder: Binder<MyViewBinding, MyType> = createSomeBinderSomewhere()
infoMap.put(someBinder)

// guaranteed type here (or runtime error if no binding of those types is found)
val binder = infoMap.get<MyViewBinding, MyType>()
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped! So I can't do all of that in Kotlin without getting a warning?

Comment: @Cilenco Well, you can also suppress it: `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")`. But otherwise, no you can't. Type erasure is part of Kotlin, and `reified` is not some magical thing that solves every problem.

Comment: @Cilenco I added a slightly more type-safe approach (which suppresses the unchecked cast, but in this case it's ok)